# Why is my frustum culling not culling on certain angles?

Tags: c++, opengl, linear-algebra, frustum, culling

My frustum culling implementation isn't working properly; what happens is it will cull when I rotate the camera to the left, but not to the right. It will also "cull" if I move the camera backward, though the distance at which the object disappears and isn't rendered is very short for this - about `6.0f` units when using the center of the object (a sphere) and the camera's position to compute the distance. Up or down movements/rotations don't really do anything.

My projection far plane is high: `500.0f`, my near plane being `0.1f`. Granted, lowering/raising the far plane doesn't really seem to affect the culling.

---

**Code**

Here's the plane computation code:

```
void Frustum::UpdateCamParams( Camera* camera )
{
    vec3 fartl, fartr, farbl, farbr;
    vec3 neartl, neartr, nearbl, nearbr;

    const vec3& camLook  = camera->GetLook();
    const vec3& camUp    = camera->GetUp();
    const vec3& camRight = camera->GetRight();
    const vec3& camPos   = camera->GetPosition();

    const float zFar    = camera->GetFarZ();
    const float zNear   = camera->GetNearZ();

    float halfFarWidth  = camera->GetFarWindowWidth() * 0.5f;
    float halfFarHeight = camera->GetFarWindowHeight() * 0.5f;

    float halfNearWidth     = camera->GetNearWindowWidth() * 0.5f;
    float halfNearHeight    = camera->GetNearWindowHeight() * 0.5f;

    const vec3& farClip = camPos + camLook * zFar;

    fartl  = farClip + ( camUp * halfFarHeight ) - ( camRight * halfFarWidth );
    fartr = farClip + ( camUp * halfFarHeight ) + ( camRight * halfFarWidth );
    farbl  = farClip - ( camUp * halfFarHeight ) - ( camRight * halfFarWidth );
    farbr = farClip - ( camUp * halfFarHeight ) + ( camRight * halfFarWidth );

    const vec3& nearClip = camPos + camLook * zNear;

    neartl  = nearClip + ( camUp * halfNearHeight ) - ( camRight * halfNearWidth );
    neartr  = nearClip + ( camUp * halfNearHeight ) + ( camRight * halfNearWidth );
    nearbl  = nearClip - ( camUp * halfNearHeight ) - ( camRight * halfNearWidth );
    nearbr  = nearClip - ( camUp * halfNearHeight ) + ( camRight * halfNearWidth );

    ////viewRay = camLook - camPos;

    // Points are set in a counter-clockwise order, for each plane

    planes[ FRUST_LEFT ].points[ 0 ] = nearbl;
    planes[ FRUST_LEFT ].points[ 1 ] = farbl;
    planes[ FRUST_LEFT ].points[ 2 ] = fartl;
    M_ComputePlane( &planes[ FRUST_LEFT ] );

    planes[ FRUST_RIGHT ].points[ 0 ] = nearbr;
    planes[ FRUST_RIGHT ].points[ 1 ] = farbr;
    planes[ FRUST_RIGHT ].points[ 2 ] = fartr;
    M_ComputePlane( &planes[ FRUST_RIGHT ] );

    planes[ FRUST_TOP ].points[ 0 ] = neartl;
    planes[ FRUST_TOP ].points[ 1 ] = neartr;
    planes[ FRUST_TOP ].points[ 2 ] = fartr;
    M_ComputePlane( &planes[ FRUST_TOP ] );

    planes[ FRUST_BOTTOM ].points[ 0 ] = nearbl;
    planes[ FRUST_BOTTOM ].points[ 1 ] = nearbr;
    planes[ FRUST_BOTTOM ].points[ 2 ] = farbr;
    M_ComputePlane( &planes[ FRUST_BOTTOM ] );

    planes[ FRUST_FAR ].points[ 0 ] = farbl;
    planes[ FRUST_FAR ].points[ 1 ] = farbr;
    planes[ FRUST_FAR ].points[ 2 ] = fartr;
    M_ComputePlane( &planes[ FRUST_FAR ] );

    planes[ FRUST_NEAR ].points[ 0 ] = nearbl;
    planes[ FRUST_NEAR ].points[ 1 ] = nearbr;
    planes[ FRUST_NEAR ].points[ 2 ] = neartr;
    M_ComputePlane( &planes[ FRUST_NEAR ] );
}
```

In a nutshell, the far clip and near clip plane centers are computed first, and then the four corners of both frustum sides are computed to allow for the point setup within the `planes` array as follows. The `planes` array is used to refer to the 6 sides of the frustum.

`M_ComputePlane` calculates the plane's normal and distance to the origin, `d`:

```
void M_ComputePlane( plane_t* p )
{
    vec3 e1 = p->points[ 2 ] - p->points[ 1 ];
    vec3 e3 = p->points[ 1 ] - p->points[ 0 ];

    vec3 normal = glm::cross( e1, e3 );

    p->normal = glm::length( normal ) > 1.0f ? glm::normalize( normal ) : normal;
    p->d      = glm::dot( p->points[ 0 ], p->normal );
}
```

Here are the intersection tests performed, each of which has been tested and basically produces the same result:

```
/*
=============================

Frustum::BoundsInSphere

    returns true in the event that the given center and radius
    are within the view frustum

=============================
*/

bool Frustum::BoundsInSphere( const vec3& center, float radius )
{
    for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
    {
        // center dot planes[ i ].normal = magnitude of projecting sphere center position onto plane normal
        // plane[ i ].d = distance from origin to plane

        float test = glm::dot( center, planes[ i ].normal ) + planes[ i ].d + radius;

        if ( test <= 0 )
            return false; // object is outside of this plane - reject!
    }

    return true;
}

/*
=============================

Frustum::BoundsInAABB_AllPoints

    Tests each vertex of the AABB and only
    returns false if all points are outside of one of
    the frustum planes. Otherwise, the object
    is considered renderable.

=============================
*/

bool Frustum::BoundsInAABB_AllPoints( const AABB& box )
{
    for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
    {
        int out = 0;

        for ( uint32_t k = 0; k < 8; ++k )
        {
            float test = glm::dot( box.Corner( k ), planes[ i ].normal ) + planes[ i ].d;

            if ( test < 0 )
                ++out;
        }

        if ( out == 8 ) // all points rejected for this plane - bail
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/*
=============================

Frustum::BoundsInAABB_Closest

    Find the closest boint of the AABB
    to frustum plane[ i ]. If that point
    has a signed distance less than 0
    to the plane, we reject it.
    Otherwise, we continue to test with the farthest
    point of the AABB to the given plane, and update
    our intersection enum accordingly.

=============================
*/

bool Frustum::BoundsInAABB_Closest( const AABB& box, frustumPlane_t* intersection )
{
    *intersection = FRUST_NONE;

    for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
    {
        const vec3& positive = box.GetPointRelativeToNormal( planes[ i ].normal, true );

        if ( M_SignedPlaneDistance( &planes[ i ], positive ) < 0 )
            return false; // closest point is outside; reject.

        const vec3& negative = box.GetPointRelativeToNormal( planes[ i ].normal, false );

        if ( M_SignedPlaneDistance( &planes[ i ], negative ) < 0 )
            *intersection = ( frustumPlane_t ) i;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: In M_ComputePlane you have a problem, you check if the length of the normal is > 1.0 to see if it is already normalised, but what if the vector has a magnitude/length less than 1.0? Then it also needs to be normalised. I would do away with the check and just always normalise.

Comment: It might be my crappy math skills too, but your d equation seems off to me. Wouldn't it pretty much amount to `||point0|| * 1 * cosθ` (1 since it is a unit vector)? This would give you the distance if point0 is codirectional with the normal, but it doesn't look like it is?

Comment: @Skurmedel my understanding is a normalized vector is normalized as long as its length doesn't exceed one. Am I wrong here? Maybe I'm wrong in your analysis of the d equation (my math skills need work as well), but I believe your solution performs the same computation, as the dot product of vectors a and b is equal to ||a||||b||cosT, where T is theta (sorry for poor format - on mobile atm)

Comment: @Skurmedal my mistake, looks like you're right. Thanks for the observations/advice :)